# ArgumentException in Fill - Expected Non-empty String

Tags: c#

I am currently developing an online examination system using C# windows application.

When I run this code I am getting the following `ArgumentException`:

> Fill: expected non empty string Parameter src table

```
private void Window1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    con.Open();
    string testTable = StudentPage.testTable;
    adp = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT TOP 5 * FROM " + testTable + " ORDER BY NEWID()", con);
    ds.Clear();
    adp.Fill(ds, testTable);
    alltables = ds.Tables;
    MyTable = alltables[testTable];
    AllRows = MyTable.Rows;

    MyRow = AllRows[0];
    GetData();
    rowPointer = 0;
    currentPage = 0;
    crtAnswer = 0;
    ViewStatus = new bool[] { true, false, false, false, false };
    isBookmarked = new bool[] { false, false, false, false, false };
    SelectedOption = new int[] { -1, -1, -1, -1, -1 };
    MyTimer.Interval = System.TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
    MyTimer.Start();
    btnFirst.IsEnabled = false;
    btnPrevious.IsEnabled = false;
    lblQuesInfo.Content = "Question 1/5";

    WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
}
```

Comment: Read the exception message. `StudentPage.testTable` is an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass an empty string to `Fill`, the error message tells it.

You could avoid it in this way:

```
if(String.IsNullOrEmppty(testTable))
    adp.Fill(ds);
else
    adp.Fill(ds, testTable);
```